# Error: Cannot find module 'semver'

Tags: firebase

Intento conectar mi proyecto con firebase y para eso ejecuto el comando

```
 firebase login
```

pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
> throw err;
> ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'semver' Require stack:
>
> - C:\Users\ltomi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\bin\firebase.js
>
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
>   at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
>
>   at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
>   at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
>
>   at Object. (C:\Users\ltomi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\bin\firebase.js:3:16)
>
>   at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
>
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
>
>   at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
>
>   at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
>
>   at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)  {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
>   requireStack: [
>   'C:\Users\ltomi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\bin\firebase.js'
>   ] }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné actualizando npm a la última versión disponible.